# Skip some or all git hooks

Tags: git, githooks

I've got a `post-checkout` hook that takes some time to run, and I want to skip it if I'm bouncing around between branches doing fix-ups.

How can I generically skip the execution of some or all `git` hooks?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conditional pre-commit hook controlled from command line for GIT: Is it possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9730937/conditional-pre-commit-hook-controlled-from-command-line-for-git-is-it-possible)

Answer (score 4):

An environment variable e.g. `DISABLE_POST_CHECKOUT` is probably what you want. Tweak your post-checkout hook with it. See also:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9730976/654952

Answer (score 2):

Here is one of the possible solutions.

Define a config key, like `my.hook` as the switch to enable or disable the hooks. Further more, `my.hook.post-checkout` to enable or disable `post-checkout` only. But you will have to deal with the keys and values in every of your hooks if you want them to work.

```
git config --global my.hook true
git config my.hook.post-checkout false
```

A `post-checkout` demo,

```
#!/bin/bash

test x`git config --get my.hook` == x"false" && exit 0
test x`git config --get my.hook.post-checkout` == x"false" && exit 0
echo hello world
```