# Disable hooks for a single git command

Tags: git, command-line-interface, hook

Given that I need to use git inside my hook scripts, I would prefer my hook scripts to not trigger hooks themselves. So I want to skip hooks on a per-command basis.

i.e. I am looking for an option like:

`git --no-hooks some-git-command`

Comment: For commit hooks, you've got the `--no-verify` option.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use:

`git -c core.hooksPath=/dev/null some-git-command`

If you are not on an Unix (no `/dev/null`) I suppose that you can use:

`git -c core.hooksPath= some-git-command`

Comment: Would you suggest a solution for disabling only one hook (e.g: *.git/hooks/post-commit*) selectively (still issuing from the command line)?

Comment: Maybe create a directory `.git/all-hooks-but-one` that contains symlinks to all hooks but the one you want to disable, add use `git -c core.hooksPath=.git/all-hooks-but-one` ? Not ideal though: some OSes do not support symlinks and you need to update the links when adding/removing/renaming new hooks.

Comment: For a record - I've found attractive solution: [hook controlled from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9730976/4241078). Simple as a hell:) Anyway **+1** for yours for the general way as well.

Answer (score 4):

Another rougher idea.

1. Just **comment lines in file** `.git/hooks/pre-commit` with symbol '#'.
2. Run single or many commands
3. Uncomment
4. Profit.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on unix, and want to disable one or more hook, you can simply do a :

```
chmod -x .git/hooks/MYHOOK ; git COMMAND ; chmod +x .git/hooks/MYHOOK;
```